# How to use {{ request.path }} in django 1.7.7

Tags: python, django, templates, request, django-1.7

I have some problem in django 1.7.7. I can not use {{ request.path }} in template with django 1.7.7, but in django 1.6, I can do that.

**Config template in setting.py to use {{ request }} in django 1.7.7:**

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
    "DIRS": [
        os.path.join(PACKAGE_ROOT, "templates"),
    ],
    "APP_DIRS": True,
    "OPTIONS": {
        "debug": DEBUG,
        "context_processors": [
            "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
            "django.core.context_processors.debug",
            "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
            "django.core.context_processors.media",
            "django.core.context_processors.static",
            "django.core.context_processors.tz",
            "django.core.context_processors.request",
            "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            "pinax_theme_bootstrap.context_processors.theme",
        ],
    },
},]
```

**and in django 1.6:**

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = [
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.core.context_processors.request",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
"pinax_theme_bootstrap.context_processors.theme",
"allauth.account.context_processors.account",
"django.core.context_processors.request"]
```

**And my template html**

```html
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load url from future %}

{% block body_class %}home{% endblock %}

{% block body_base %}
 {{ request.path }}
 <div class="row">
  <form class="answer-question-form" method="POST" action="/add_answer_question">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="col-md-12" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
     <label>Question</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" name="question" placeholder="Question...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 col-sm-12">
     <label>Choose type question</label>
     <select class="form-control" name="categories">
      <option value="01">1</option>
      <option value="02">2</option>
      <option value="03">3</option>
      <option value="04">4</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
     <label>Type answer</label>
     <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified choose-type-answer">
      <li class="active"><a class="type-answer" href="#" id="type-answer-01">Radio</a></li>
      <li><a class="type-answer" href="#" id="type-answer-02">Check</a></li>
      <li><a class="type-answer" href="#" id="type-answer-03">Seek</a></li>
     </ul>
     <input name="type-answers" type="hidden" value="01">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group answers col-md-12">
     <label>Answers</label>
     <input name="answer" type="text" class="form-control answer-detail" placeholder="Input answer here...">
     <input name="answer" type="text" class="form-control answer-detail" placeholder="Input answer here...">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
     <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>
 </div>
{% endblock %}
```

So, I added "django.core.context_processors.request" to template but it doesn't work.

Plese help me! Thanks

Comment: can you show a view code?

Comment: I just put {{ reuqest.path }} in html but I don't see any thing in screen when I use django 1.7.7. But  in django 1.6, I can see current url in template

Comment: I know, but you can update the question with a view sample code? i think the problem can be in the view.

Comment: @DuyTrần please show us your view where you render the template.

Comment: @ozgur That's line 9. {{ request.path }}

Comment: @DuyTrần the views, not the template. :), i post a answer, maybe it solve the problem.

Comment: @PauloPessoa, oh I'm sory. I'm confused

Comment: call the html template using render and pass context_dict which include {path : request.path }

Comment: @PauloPessoa thank you very much

Comment: @DuyTrần i mean the view function you wrote in `views.py`.

Comment: @SANDHYALALKUMAR I understand but I don't want to do that

Comment: @DuyTrần you are using render_to_response?

Comment: @DuyTrần if you use render_to_response without pass a requestcontext, rewrite your views returns to 
return render(request, 'app/template.html', {"foo": "bar"})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the :

```
"OPTIONS": {
        "debug": DEBUG,
        "context_processors": [
            "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
            "django.core.context_processors.debug",
            "django.core.context_processors.i18n",
            "django.core.context_processors.media",
            "django.core.context_processors.static",
            "django.core.context_processors.tz",
            "django.core.context_processors.request",
            "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            "pinax_theme_bootstrap.context_processors.theme",
        ],
    },
```

Add :

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
"django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.core.context_processors.tz",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages"
"django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

Nowhere in the [documentation 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext), they mention the "OPTIONS", only in the [doc 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext),

If you aren't rendering the request, like docs says:

> If you’re using Django’s render_to_response() shortcut to populate a
>   template with the contents of a dictionary, your template will be
>   passed a Context instance by default (not a RequestContext). To use a
>   RequestContext in your template rendering, use the render() shortcut
>   which is the same as a call to render_to_response() with a
>   context_instance argument that forces the use of a RequestContext.

Maybe the problem is on yours views. try to use [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) instead of render_to_response (if you use it)

Comment: Paulo Pesoa. Ok, it works. Thanks bro :D. Nice to meet you.

Comment: Paulo Pesoa I did. Thanks again :D